# Conjugacy classes of a finite solvable group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite solvable group with $Z(G)\neq1$. If for any ‎$‎1‎\neq‎ z\in Z(G)‎$‎, there exist ‎$‎g, x\in G‎$‎ such that $z=[g,x]\in G^{'}$, can we say that $cl_G(x)=cl_G(zx)$?

Answer (score 5):

We can say $cl_G(x)=cl_G(zx)$ and you don't need to assume $G$ is finite or solvable:

The assumptions $z=[g,x]=g^{-1}x^{-1}gx$ and $z\in Z(G)$ give $zxg=xgz=gx$ so $zx=gxg^{-1}$. Hence $x$ and $zx$ are conjugate in $G$ so $cl_G(x)=cl_G(zx)$.